# Express server res.sendFile() giving error about path

Tags: html, express, tailwind-css

I am making a newsletter-signUp page and if it is successful i want to send `success.html` file and if not then `failure.html` file but when I send the file using `res.sendFile` and `dirname` it gives error of  `TypeError: path must be a string to res.sendFIle` and if I use `fileURLToPath` & `path.dirname` to get the path, it works fine.
What is the error here because simple `dirname` is sending my `index.html` file but not these two

> Sending the index.html using dirname

```
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.sendFile(dirname, "/public/index.html")
})
```

> Sending the success and failure html files..**ERROR PART**

```
  const request = https.request(url,options,(response)=>{
    if(response.statusCode === 200){
      res.sendFile(dirname, "/success.html")
    }else{
      res.sendFile(dirname, "/failure.html")
    }
    response.on("data",(data)=>{
      console.log(JSON.parse(data))
    })
  })
```

> Works if used these

```
const __fileName = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirName = path.dirname(__fileName)
```

```
  const request = https.request(url,options,(response)=>{
    if(response.statusCode === 200){
      res.sendFile(__dirName + "/success.html")
      // res.send("Its done!")
    }else{
      res.sendFile(__dirName + "/failure.html")
    }
    response.on("data",(data)=>{
      console.log(JSON.parse(data))
    })
  })
```

I wish to use only the default `dirname` and not the variable made through `fileURL` and `path`

I cant figure out how to solve it and I did put the files inside `public` folder but didn't work

Comment: The second parameter to [sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) should be an options object. Are you perhaps meaning to use `path.resolve()`? Also, what is `dirname`? Did you mean [__dirname](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#__dirname)?

Comment: In short, I think you want `res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html")`. Note that you cannot use `__dirname` in ES6 modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an ESM module (where you use `import` and `export`), there is no default definition of `__filename` or `__dirname`.  You have to manufacture your own with this:

```
const __fileName = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirName = path.dirname(__fileName)
```

like you do in your last code example.  That's how you do it in an ESM module file.  Only CommonJS modules (that use `require()` and `module.exports`) have `__filename` and `__dirname` by default.

---

As for your examples where you are trying to do this:

```
res.sendFile(dirname, "/success.html")
```

that is just clearly wrong.  It's not clear where `dirname` comes from or what its value is (I would guess its not a string based on the error message) AND, `res.sendFile()` does not accept two strings as arguments so you're just passing the wrong arguments.  If you pass two arguments, the first must be the full path and the second argument is an options object.  You don't pass two strings to it.  The method signature is this: `res.sendFile(path [, options] [, fn])`.